# Erro em pesquisa no django

Tags: python, django, tabela-banco-de-dados

Olá estou criando um projeto no django e ao realizar uma busca de uma Taginfo com base numa Tag que possui a foreignkey para Taginfo. Estou recebendo o seguinte erro na linha 99 da view.

```
TypeError at /datasources/get/1/
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Taginfo'
```

Aqui está o model das classes relacionadas.

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    objects = GChartsManager()

    idtag = models.IntegerField(db_column='idTAG', primary_key=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    desvio = models.FloatField(db_column='DEVIATION', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tempo_max = models.IntegerField(db_column='TIME_MAX', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    conv_rate = models.IntegerField(db_column='CONV_RATE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    taginfo_idtaginfo1 = models.ForeignKey('Taginfo', db_column='tagInfo_idTAGINFO')  # Field name made lowercase.
    datasource_idestacao_meteo = models.ForeignKey(Datasource, db_column='datasource_idDATASOURCE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'id = %s / id tagInfo => %s' % (self.idtag, self.taginfo_idtaginfo1)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tag'


class Taginfo(models.Model):

    objects = GChartsManager()

    idtaginfo = models.IntegerField(db_column='idTAGINFO', primary_key=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
    descricao = models.CharField(db_column='DESCRIPTION', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'name = %s / description = %s' % (self.nome, self.descricao)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'taginfo'
```

Aqui está a view em que ocorre o erro.

```
def datasource(request, datasource_id = 1):
# if there is
if Datasource.objects.filter(idestacao_meteo=datasource_id).count()>0 :
    result = Datasource.objects.get(idestacao_meteo=datasource_id)
    #if there is tags on this datasource
    tags = None
    tagsInfos = None
    if Tag.objects.filter(datasource_idestacao_meteo = datasource_id).count>0:
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(datasource_idestacao_meteo = datasource_id)
        tagInfos = Taginfo.objects.filter()         
        for tag in tags:
            idTaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1
            tagInfos = tagInfos.filter(idtaginfo = idTaginfo)
        '''
        tagInfo = {'' : 0} 
        for tag in tags:
            tagInfo[tag.idtag] = Taginfo.objects.get(idtaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1)
        '''
    else:
        tags = None
        tagsInfos = None        
    return render_to_response('Datasource/datasource.html',
        #{'datasource' : result, 'tags' : tags}
        {'datasource' : result, 'tags' : tags, 'tagInfos' : tagInfos}
    )
else:
    return render_to_response('Datasource/datasourceDoesNotExist.html',
        {'datasource_id' : datasource_id }
    )
```

Não sei pq esse erro ocorre pq o ambos campos são int e um é foreign key e o outro a primary key.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Qual é a linha 99 da view?

Comment: Linha 99 -> tagInfos = tagInfos.filter(idtaginfo = idTaginfo)

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei. Nesse caso, veja minha resposta, se ainda tiver dúvidas pode perguntar.

Answer (score 1):

Na linha:

```
idTaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1
```

Você deveria usar:

```
idTaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1.idtaginfo
```

Pois muito embora no modelo `taginfo_idtaginfo1` seja uma chave estrangeira (e no BD esteja representada por um número), nas *instâncias do modelo* ela é um objeto complexo, não podendo ser usada para filtrar um campo que espera um número:

```
tagInfos = tagInfos.filter(idtaginfo = idTaginfo) # idtaginfo é um IntegerField
```

Comment: eu coloquei do modo que vc falou no código `código`

Comment: eu coloquei do modo que vc falou no código 
`idTaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1_id`  
e também 
`idTaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1.idtaginfo`  
ambos não dão erro porém não retornam nenhuma pesquisa no BD, ao fazer o teste pelo shell do Django eu recebi o erro 
" `...has no atribute ' taginfo_idtaginfo1_id '  "

Comment: @Nathan Ops, desculpe, não percebi que seu modelo `TagInfo` possuía uma chave primária customizada (i.e. ela não se chama `id`). Atualizei a resposta, deve funcionar agora. Caso *ainda assim* não resolva, amanhã farei uns testes e volto a essa pergunta.

Comment: obrigado pela dica, ela não gera erro porém também não me retorna nenhum item,kkk. No shell ocorre um erro ao utilizar 
`tag = Tag.objects.filter(taginfo_idtaginfo1.idtaginfo = 2)`
o erro gerado é `keyword can´t be an expression`
porém ao utilizar o código 
`tag = Tag.objects.filter(taginfo_idtaginfo1__idtaginfo = 2)` um objeto é retornado, que é o quê deveria ocorrer. Eu vi essa forma de pesquisa no link [https://django-portuguese.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/topics/db/queries.html#atalho-para-pk]

Comment: @ mgibsonbr porém este mesmo código gera erro no projeto, o erro é
 `'Tag' object has no attribute 'taginfo_idtaginfo1__idtaginfo'` não entendi como no shell pode funcionar e no projeto não.